# Use JSON data from service

Tags: c#, json, web-services, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

The code below is supposed to get data from a web service, a plug it into a defined list "Groups". This is for a windows 8 metro app.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(App.DataServiceUrl + "/productcategory");
var Groups = new List<GroupList>();

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var prods = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
    foreach (var data in prods)
    {
        var dataGroup = new GroupList
              (
                 data.term_id,
                  data.name,
                 data.slug,
                   data.description,
                  data.taxonomy
              );
        Groups.Add(dataGroup);

    }
}
```

GroupList:

```
public class GroupList : SampleDataCommon
{


    public GroupList(String uniqueId, String title, String subtitle, String imagePath, String description)


 : base(uniqueId, title, subtitle, imagePath, description)
```

}

One example of the data from the service is:

```
[{"term_id":"64","name":"Argentina","slug":"argentina","term_group":"0","term_taxonomy_id":"64","taxonomy":"product_cat","description":"","parent":"13","count":"20","meta_id":"154","woocommerce_term_id":"64","meta_key":"order","meta_value":"0","cat_ID":"64","category_count":"20","category_description":"","cat_name":"Argentina","category_nicename":"argentina","category_parent":"13"},...]
```

But the application doesn't recognize the json values here:

```
data.term_id,
data.name,
data.slug,
data.description,
data.taxonomy
```

Instead when I run the application I get this error:

"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path", line 4, position 2"

I am trying to get the values of term_id, name etc. from the web service json and use it in my app. How to I do this? What am I doing wrong? Hwo do I use the JSON values?

Returned from json2csharp:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string term_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string term_group { get; set; }
    public string term_taxonomy_id { get; set; }
    public string taxonomy { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string parent { get; set; }
    public string count { get; set; }
    public string meta_id { get; set; }
    public string woocommerce_term_id { get; set; }
    public string meta_key { get; set; }
    public string meta_value { get; set; }
    public string cat_ID { get; set; }
    public string category_count { get; set; }
    public string category_description { get; set; }
    public string cat_name { get; set; }
    public string category_nicename { get; set; }
    public string category_parent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You say `The data from the web service is in XML format.`  but use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. Also you say `One example of the data returned from the new service is:` But the data is already in json.

Comment: The first web service that the code works with returned data in XML, but the new service that I am now trying to use, is in JSON. I am now attempting to use the JSON service.

Comment: Tester, Then why did you post that unrelated info? What does it have to do with what you are trying to do?

Comment: It was my mistake, I made some edits. Trying to work fro  my phone atm.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You still need to deserialize the JSON string returned by the service into some kind of object to access its properties as is currently being done in your example.

Comment: I made some edits. Does this help.

Comment: How do I map select JSON values pulled from the URL, to the values in GroupList?

Comment: @Tester `How do I map`? only you can know. Your json doesn't contain fields other than description. Who knows what is title, subtitle, imagepath etc. ?

Comment: @L.B I made some edits to simplify the question and the problem. Please see above.

Comment: @Tester I am loo lazy to write an answer. Just post your json to [this site](http://json2csharp.com/) and use the returned class instead of `dynamic`. That way you can continue with type-safe coding.

Comment: @L.B See edits above. But this doesn't help my problem, or I don't see how it does?

Answer (score 0):

You're currently using different dataProd properties as parameter values for a new instance of CategoryList. You would need to decide what kind of type deriving from GroupList you want to use to hold the new data and replace the instantiation of CategoryList with that type, and initializing it (via constructor or properties) so that the new data goes into Groups

Comment: I'm sorry, that was mistake by me. See the edits above please.